# Is it a good practice to include the .c file on its own .h file?

Tags: c, header-files

It seems to be more productive, at the end of the header file you include the .c file in the following case

```
#ifndef CHIP8_H
#define CHIP8_H

//header struct here

#include "chip8.c"
#endif
```

the header file is included in the chip8.c file and you don't need to add the chip8.c file into the compiler, is it ill advised to do this?.

If i include the .h file where i need, it just works.

Comment: No, you should almost never include a `.c` file. Compile it and link it with your executable.

Comment: Including your `.c` files in your `.h` files makes no sense.  Suppose 10 different files want to include the header file.  Then, at best (if the included functions were all static), you'd end up with *ten copies of the included functions*.  Don't try to go off-road with this until you understand it far, far better.  Put your declarations in your `.h` files and your function definitions and variable definitions in your `.c` files.

Comment: Can i #include <stdint.h> if i need specific data types though?

Comment: Of course you can include another header in a header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic reaction to this will be a big "no" and there are several practical reasons for that.

As others have mentioned, the distinction between .h and .c files is that of the interface versus an implementation. In some cases, different .c files may implement different versions of a given interface. E.g.

```
// sort.h
void sort(int *array, size_t size);
```

Could be implemented by

```
// quicksort.c
#include "sort.h"
void sort(int *array, size_t size) {
  // Quicksort algorithm
}
```

or

```
// bubblesort.c 
#include "sort.h"
void sort(int *array, size_t size) {
  // Bubble sort algorithm
}
```

A second thing is that a .c file can have "private" elements in the form of static variables, functions, types, definitions, etc. which are not published outside the module.

E.g., a .c file could have:

```
static unsigned counter = 0;
#define MAX_SIZE 1000
```

Inside a single .c file it is fine to use fairly generic names since they will not be visible outside the module and thus not clutter the global namespace. This is particularly important in large applications. If the .c file were included in the header, then such symbols would be visible/defined in all modules which include that header.

These are just two examples of potential problems which such an approach would lead to. There are numerous others. Hence, in this is (as it often turns out) an example of good old practices not just being old, but also good.

Answer (score 4):

No, no, a thousand times no. Here's why.

Header .h files *define* the interface, the API. Source .c files *implement* it. The consumers of header files are other source files that use the stuff implemented in the source file.

More recently dreamed-up languages have classes, public and private methods and properties, inheritance, interfaces, and traits, and all that really good interface definition stuff. But C -- old school Kernighan and Ritchie C -- has .h files and .c files for that.